# CORS not blocking request

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I have created this class

```
package com.jswone.scm.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")  // Use allowedOriginPatterns instead of allowedOrigins
                .allowedMethods()
                .allowedHeaders("POST")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

`

I have this controller api

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/list")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> getOrderList() throws InterruptedException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Even though I haven't added GET operation in the CORS, it's still allowing me to call this get api written. The bean is initialized. By Spring is not using the WebMvcConfigurer. Can this be a issue related any dependency conflicts?

Sharing my pom.xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jswone.scm</groupId>
        <artifactId>scm-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom-parent.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>


    <artifactId>scm-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.jswone.scm.SCM</start-class>
    </properties>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jswone</groupId>
            <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jswone.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>scm-internal-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${openAPI.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--                    <fork>false</fork>-->
                    <mainClass>com.jswone.scm.SCM</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any leads will be helpful. Tried different approaches on setting up CORS.

Any leads will be helpful. Tried different approaches on setting up CORS.
Nothing worked.

Comment: *"it's still allowing me to call this get api"* - Where/how are you calling it?

Comment: Am calling the api using postman request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: makes sense. Thanks David new to this.

Comment: does the same happens if we trigger api from swagger? I have triggered from swagger, still its not blocking

Comment: Why are you *expecting* the browser to block the request from swagger?  What is the URL of the swagger page and what is the URL of the API?  Based on your research into what CORS is, why does this result surprise you?

Comment: swagger url: /swagger-ui/index.html
api url: GET /fg/list
Theres no CORS response, when trying to hit the api.
Actually I have blocked the GET request here:
cors.allowedHeaders=Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,access_token,X-Request-ID
cors.allowedMethods=HEAD,POST,PUT
cors.maxAge=3600

Comment: seems like my understanding was bit wrong. Tried creating an HTML and hitting the API. working as expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

GET, POST keywords should be in allowedMethods
like this.

```
.allowedMethods("POST")
.allowedHeaders("*")
```

If it is not working,
try to delete @EnableWebMvc annotation.
When you use @EnableWebMvc and WebMvcConfigurer together, some of Spring Boot's default settings may be ignored